# Measure MySQL Transactions Per Second

Tags: mysql, percona

How can I measure transactions per second on a MySQL server? I came across this post ([How to measure "queries per second"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4737047/how-to-measure-queries-per-second)) but this more talks about queries executed per second.  Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean SQL transactions bracketed by `START TRANSACTION` and `COMMIT TRANSACTION`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to monitor database transaction?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566710/how-to-monitor-database-transaction)